# Hi, does anyone know where is the error of this query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

does anyone know where is the error of this query?
Its returning no results.

Thanks!

```sql
SELECT
smt.SubscriberKey,
smt.CreateDateTime AS Sent_Date,
smt.Mobile,
smt.MessageText AS SMS_Text,
j.JourneyName
FROM _smsmessagetracking smt
JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON ja.JourneyActivityObjectID = smt.JBActivityID
JOIN _Journey j ON ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
WHERE
j.JourneyName IN ('Journey_test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  respective field for JBActivityID in `_SMSMessageTracking` is **ActivityID** in `_JourneyActivity` not JourneyActivityObjectID

So it should be like this:

```SQL
SELECT
smt.SubscriberKey,
smt.CreateDateTime AS Sent_Date,
smt.Mobile,
smt.MessageText AS SMS_Text,
j.JourneyName
FROM _smsmessagetracking smt
JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON ja.ActivityID = smt.JBActivityID
JOIN _Journey j ON ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
WHERE
j.JourneyName IN ('Journey_test')
```

Comment: Thank you very much... how about connect the same logical for whatsapp menssages?